# change the categories and series in highcharts by select button?

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

Here is the example of what I done so far,

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Sriganesh/LnAq3/57/)**

I have a drop down button on the top with values. I want to change the chart series and categories by selecting the drop down.

So, basically i want my chart to respond with the following logic:

```
if ($('#hidden_stages').val() == 1) {
  categories: show_hidden_stage_categories,
  series: show_hidden_stage_series,
} else if ($('#hidden_stages').val() == 1) {
  categories: hide_hidden_stage_categories,
  series: hide_hidden_stage_series,
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate categories, you can use [setCategories](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setCategories) function

Comment: I want to refresh the whole chart series, categories and the legends by changing the dropdown. :-( Do you have any example?

Comment: Series can be updated by http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update, so when you cobine both funciton, you will achieve your goal.